# Android Dropbox API auth URL issue

Tags: java, android, dropbox

So I'm testing out the dropbox api and setup everything so far according to the tutorial up to where it asks for authorization. It brings me to the page that asks for my authorization where I click allow then the next pages URL after clicking allow looks to start with db-"my app key here" etc but the page says unknown URL scheme and won't continue. Looks like I may be missing something but not sure what exactly.

Comment: When you are constructing your URL, did you tried avoiding quotes and spaces after "db-" ?

Comment: yes it's just "db-mykey" mykey obviously being the key they gave me. No space or anything. I also get a verification email from dropbox saying I've connected an app but every time I run the check to see if there is a linked account it says there isn't.

Comment: I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15810530/434171 ... it seems to be a bug in Chrome, but I've downloaded the last version of it in Google Play and I still have the same error.