# Dropbox API and Android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm trying to read a file from Dropbox in my Android app (I'm using the emulator).
Everything seems fine: the browser is opened and I introduce my credentials, then I click 'Allow' and then the next message appears in the browser:

```
Webpage not available
The webpage at db-jar8vuiz4j3nlns://1/connect?oauth_token=...&oath_token_secret=...&uid=...
might be temporarily down or it may have moved to a new web address.
```

So, what's happening? It's really a `temporarily` error of Dropbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've resolved this installing the last version of Dropbox Android app.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Chrome:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181186

It's already fixed, though the fixed version may not be released yet.

Comment: Well, I've tested the HelloWorld app included in the Dropbox SDK and it works perfectly, so I don't think that its a bug in Chrome (I've tested my app in Firefox also). What is going on?